# why is my connected peers so few and blocks syncronising so slow even it stops

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, wallets, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

it took so much time to do the syncronising but still not completed, I want know if the syncronising is always this slow, or is there some way to make it quicker?[image]

Comment: Hi Wang, which mist version is that?

Comment: Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-5-2

Comment: First thing to try is downloading [0-7-2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases).

Comment: Second, check what the logs in `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\Mist\node.log` say. And finally, if you find something out, [update your question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/3355/edit) so we can provide a good answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question as to why this happens, but it will help understand a bit about what your situation is.

Generally, I start `geth` in the Terminal (I use OSX) and watch the activity. Firstly it tells me what the last block was that I downloaded - which I then look up on any of the block explorers. This tells me how far behind I am.

The next thing I watch for is the frequency of the downloaded blocks. Normally this isn't fast - I mean it's not a super fast stream of information filling up the screen, just a simple line of information every couple of seconds or so.

When I am caught up I then start Mist and it loads pretty fast then.

It's important to note that deplying anything through mist requires the blockchain to be up to date for it to be responsive. If not, then even sending transactions is going to "appear" slow.